# how to bind a data-click to a div populated in a template with kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui, mustache, kendo-mobile

I'm trying to populate a template with kendo UI where I attach a data-click to some `<button>`.

The template is populated after an ajax request `(when().done())` and the `data-click` doesn't seem to work. Why ? how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Code: (I'm using kendo ui and Moustache)
html

```
    <!-- Templatr for Event Lists -->
    <script id="listTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

        {{#each this}}
            <div class="post">
                <div class="post-content" data-index="{{@index}}" data-id="{{id}}">
                    <div class="post-header"> 
                        <span class="outing-name">{{name}}</span> - {{type}}
                        <br /> at <span class="outing-category">{{place.name}}</span> ( {{dist}} km)
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-image">
                        <img src="{{pic}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-desc">
                        {{{short_desc}}} [...]
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="post-actions">
                    <a data-role="button" data-click="notifyEvent" class="buttonNotify" data-id="{{id}}" data-name="{{name}}" data-type="{{type}}">I want to go</a>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button">Friends</a>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-id="{{id}}">More details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using  `data-bind:"click: notifyEvent"` and have the function initialized in your ViewModel like this :

```
 var viewModel = kendo.observable({

                notifyEvent: notifyEvent,

                ... other functions, objects or kendo.data.DataSource...

            });
    function notifyEvent{ ..do stuff here... }


 $.extend(window, {
        viewModel: viewModel 
    });
```

be sure to have your view initialized something like this:

```
<div data-role="view" id="ListView"  data-title="ListView" data-layout="listTemplate"  data-model="viewModel">
```

hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: I can't have it working. what does ` $.extend(window, {
        viewModel: viewModel 
    });` stands for?
Also, can i attach a `data-model` to a layout ?